# Cannot get vertical align: top to work correctly for inline-block, fixed height elements.

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have an issue where I have been trying to get several elements in a container to be vertically aligned to the top of this container. The elements SHOULD NOT have any space between those at the top, and those below them. This should be collapsed.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 category_links">
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 83px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Brands And Categories</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="men">Men</a></li>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.footer_menu {
  width: 24%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

What it looks like on the demo site:

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upyV9.png)

Comment: maybe you can use list-style: none in css

Comment: @BorisP I have tried this, but the boxes are persistently staying in their line-box state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the heights and add the below CSS

HTML

> ```
> <div class="row">
> <div class="col-md-8 category_links">
>   <div class="footer_menu">
>     <h3 class="secondary">Brands And Categories</h3>
>     <ul>
>       <li><a href="men">Men</a></li>
>       <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
>       <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
>   <div class="footer_menu" >
>     <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
>     <ul>
>       <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
>       <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
>   <div class="footer_menu" >
>     <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
>     <ul>
>       <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
>       <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
>   <div class="footer_menu" >
>     <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
>     <ul>
>       <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
>       <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
>   <div class="footer_menu" >
>     <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
>     <ul>
>       <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
>       <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
>   <div class="footer_menu" >
>     <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
>     <ul>
>       <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
>       <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
>   <div class="footer_menu" >
>     <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
>     <ul>
>       <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
>       <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

CSS

> .category_links {
>       column-gap: 0.5em;
>       column-width: 11em;
>       float: left;
>    }
>
> .footer_menu {
>       display: inline-block;
>       font-weight: bold;
>       margin: 2px;
>       padding: 0;
>       width: 98%; }

Comment: Thank you kind sir, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.footer_menu {
  width: 24%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-table;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 category_links">
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 83px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Brands And Categories</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="men">Men</a></li>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_menu" style="height: 64px;">
        <h3 class="secondary">Help And Policy</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this what you need?

Comment: it doesn't change how they are laid out unfortunately. The divs that wrap onto a new line do not collapse the spacing above them.

Comment: I would like to help, but it seems that i'm lost in translation :). please, show me an example and I will try to help. If you look in link to image, it's the same